# htaccess и страница без стиля (Смотрите внутри)

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

Есть файлы: ".htaccess", "index.php", содержание ".htaccess":

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

И "index.php":

```
<?php
$asd = $_GET['page'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Page: <?php echo $asd; ?></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**В стилях указано что фон синий и цвет текста белый**, при открытии url:
"**localhost/**", "**localhost/3r34r**" всё нормально и всё корректно работает, НО при открытии url:
"**localhost/page/1**" пишет что страница 1 но **не работает стиль**, как исправить?

P.s. В mod_rewrite ничего не понимаю, может кто-нибудь объяснит как это работает?

Comment: Путь к стилям/картинкам/и т.д. прописывайте полным с указанием домена.

Comment: @Visman, домен то зачем?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, а чем домен мешает?

Comment: @Visman, деплоить невозможно, сейчас localhost, и для релиза все переписывать?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, зачем что-то переписывать, если все пути формируются функцией/методом на основании настроек конфигурации!? :)

Comment: @Visman, такой подход видел у многих php разработчиков, но ни один не может ответить нахрена вообще это делать (доказать что хорошо настроил кэширование и сервер не падает?))).

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, ну так чтобы не менять пути в шаблонах при перемещении сайта/форума, например из папки в поддомен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прописывайте абсолютный путь к стилям от корня сайта:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Либо указывайте base href в head:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, а почему так?

Comment: он у вас лез искать этот файл в localhost/page/1/css/style.css, тоесть относительно папки, в которой находитесь. первый слэш говорит что искать надо от корня сайта